# Connect to Server using SSL Socket with the help of certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a SSL Server which is written in Java using SSL Socket.Server is running properly.Now i need to connect to Server using client app.

Client code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\cacerts.jks");        
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

try {
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 800);

    InputStream inputstream = System.in;
    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

    OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
    BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);

    bufferedwriter.write("test"+"\n");
    bufferedwriter.flush();
    bufferedwriter.close();

} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the above code,i'm using the same keystore file as truststore.

Is this good idea to use same keystore file as truststore at client side? if not how can i connect to server in secure manner?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Everything working fine.But i don't know whether it is a good idea to use the same keystore at client side?

Comment: Ideally, you should have a separate trust store with the certificate for the client to use.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: look at the following post https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html

Comment: Are you telling to 
1.Create a Keystore. 
2.Then Import the certificate into another truststore. 
Use this truststore at client.

Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above code,i'm using the same keystore file as truststore.

No you're not. You're only using a truststore. If you're using a keystore, you must specify it:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ...);        
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ...);
```

and you should certainly ***not*** use the same file for both.

Comment: I'm using the same keystore file which was used in server in client as truststore.How to create a truststore for client?

Comment: That is radically insecure. It leaks the server's private key. Don't do that. Export the server certificate to a file and import it into a new empty truststore file for the client.

Comment: First i need to export the certificate from Server Keystore,then make the truststore file from that certificate and pack the truststore files with all the client.

is this idea is secure?

Comment: Yes. Exporting the certificate doesn't export the private key.